# Use of profile attribute in HTML head tag

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What is the use of profile attributes in the HTML `<head>` tag?

I happened to read about it in here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp.

I could not understand this(http://www.w3.org/2002/12/namespace) either, since it is too technical (for me).

I have never used it. What is the purpose it serves?

Comment: As the `profile` attribute is obsolete in HTML5, see also the question: [What rel=profile is for?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16636870/1591669)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The URI in the profile attribute points to a document containing information regarding metadata. Profiles defines properties that may be used by the `HTML meta tag` and the `HTML link tag`. There are no prescribed formats for profiles. The profile attribute is no longer supported in HTML 5.

Comment: @ detj thanks for your answer. Have you ever seen any real life application?

Comment: @rajakvk: haven't come across yet! I think its probably a property:value pair for adding more metadata to pages, but now we have better things like XML. maybe another reason why it is being disposed

Comment: @rajakvk: Value of the profile attribute is a URL. The URL points to a document that contains a set of rules. User agents can read those rules to understand the information contained within the meta tags. I got my answer from https://www.w3resource.com/html/head/HTML-head-tag-and-element.php

Answer (score 27):

`HTML5` has dropped the profile attribute from the **`head`** element ([details](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/DroppedAttributeProfile)).
You could however, use a `rel` attribute to the links to achieve this.

So, instead of

```
    <HEAD profile="http://www.acme.com/profiles/core">
```

it is now

```
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
```

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.3),

> The profile attribute of the HEAD specifies the location of a meta
>   data profile. The value of the profile attribute is a URI. User agents
>   may use this URI in two ways:
>
> 1. As a globally unique name. User agents may be able to recognize the name (without actually retrieving the profile) and perform some
>      activity based on known conventions for that profile. For instance,
>      search engines could provide an interface for searching through
>      catalogs of HTML documents, where these documents all use the same
>      profile for representing catalog entries.
> 2. As a link. User agents may dereference the URI and perform some activity based on the actual definitions within the profile (e.g.,
>      authorize the usage of the profile within the current HTML document).
>      This specification does not define formats for profiles.

Simply put, [XMDP](http://gmpg.org/xmdp/) introduced a simple way to define URLs and meanings used in an element, to read and write by both humans and machines as a dictionary of meta information. It was an initial attempt to achieve relations between elements.

To read more on this, find the references listed at the end of the answer.

IMO, things have really improved in the recent past to achieve semantic relations thanks to introduction and implementations of [Rich Snippets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Searchology#Rich_Snippet), which allows multiple formats for implementing structured data.
More information is available at [schema.org](http://schema.org/) and [FAQ](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1211158&topic=1088472&ctx=topic).

Here is the list of supported markup formats

1. [Microdata](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035&topic=1088472&ctx=topic)
2. [Microformats](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146897&topic=1088472&ctx=topic)
3. [RDFa](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146898)

... [More Details](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic)

With recent updates, there is also linking of author, and content published ([Google+ only](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986)), by adding this :

```
<link href="https://plus.google.com/{+PageId}" rel="publisher" />
```

References / Further reading :

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#profiles
2. http://gmpg.org/xmdp/
3. http://microformats.org/wiki/html5-profile#Section_7.4.1_-_The_HEAD_element
4. http://microformats.org/wiki/profile-uris
5. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic

Answer (score 8):

The actual HTML 4 specification as opposed to the background on name spaces in general explains it better. Check out:
http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#profiles

One real life use is to make it clear that your meta-data is not just an arbitrary system by you, but adheres to a system some one came up with.

So for example, you may want to use the Dublin Core specification for your meta data. On a web page you would state this in the HEAD element using the profile attribute and then your meta tags would use Dublin Core elements like so:

```
<head profile="http://dublincore.org/documents/2008/08/04/dc-html/">
<meta name="DC.date" content="2010-11-22">
<meta name="DC.format" content="text/html">
<meta name="DC.contributor" content="Dublin Core Metadata Initiative>
<meta name="DC.language" content="en">
```

Answer (score 2):

Often, the header of a document contains a number of `<meta>` tags used to convey
additional information about the document to the browser. In the future, authors
may use predefined profiles of standard document metadata to better describe their
documents. The profile attribute supplies the URL of the profile associated with the
current document.

The format of a profile and how a browser might use it are not yet defined; this
attribute is primarily a placeholder for future development.

FROM::
HTML & XHTML: The Definitive
Guide, Sixth Edition, by Chuck Musciano and Bill Kennedy. Copyright 2007
O’Reilly Media, Inc., 978-0-596-52732-7.

Comment: Why did you edit this? The head element has a lot of other types of tags besides meta ones. (like title for instance) I don't think the authors intended to limit the discussion to only meta tags but you would need to consult them for clarification.