# What rel=profile is for?

Tags: html, relationship, rel, microformats

While doing the HTML for my new template, I stumbled across a new meta tag

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
```

What's this for? I found it linking to this [page](http://gmpg.org/xfn/11), and through Google I found this [Microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-profile) but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In HTML 4.01, there is the [`profile` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-profile) for the `head` element:

> This attribute specifies the location of one or more meta data profiles, separated by white space. For future extensions, user agents should consider the value to be a list even though this specification only considers the first URI to be significant.

It is used to link to [meta data profiles](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#profiles).

In HTML5, the `profile` attribute was [dropped](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-head-profile).

As an alternative to it, the [`rel` value `profile`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-profile) could be used (with [several advantages](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-profile#advantages) over the `profile` attribute). [RFC 6906](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6906) describes the "`profile` Link Relation Type".

An example format for such meta data profiles (whether for the `profile` attribute or the `rel` value) is [XMDP](http://microformats.org/wiki/XMDP): XHTML Meta Data Profiles. It is defined at http://gmpg.org/xmdp/:

> a simple XHTML-based format for defining HTML meta data profiles easy to read and write by both humans and machines

---

In your example, the profile for XFN is used, the [Xhtml Friends Network (archive.org link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130513141051/http://gmpg.org/xfn/):

> a simple way to represent human relationships using hyperlinks

Comment: Can it be safely deleted? What is its purpose? None of this really tells me its purpose.

Comment: @felwithe: The whole answer is about its purpose: it’s used to specify metadata profiles. Whether or not you can safely delete it from a document cannot be answered without knowing why it’s there / without knowing if there’s a consumer making use of it.

Comment: It literally doesn't even say what a metadata profile is.

Comment: I know this is old but it may still be useful to anyone with a similar question as I do now. It can be frustrating when you come across this jargon-like links especially in WordPress and you have no idea what it is. Check this article https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173117/why-is-there-a-link-tag-with-rel-profile-pointing-to-gmpg-org I believe it explains better.

Comment: @adegukLoggcity - That link did not explain *anything* better.  It was just more jargon.

Answer (score 4):

It's related to `XHTML Friends Network` (relation between links)

But **don't waste your time on it.**

It's useless enough to be dropped from the HTML5 draft. I'd suggest against using it.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417789/4718434