# Is it possible to include more than one link tag in an HTML document with the same rel="..." value?

Tags: html, wordpress, microformats, hcard, xfn

I am using the default wordpress theme (*twentyseventee*) and I see that the header includes the following:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
```

I would like to also use the [hCard microformat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCard) to describe my info (photo, name, email, etc.) However, the *hCard* requires the following link:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://microformats.org/profile/hcard">
```

Now I am thinking that if I have two links with `rel="profile"` it is very likely that the search engines will drop one or the other.

Is there any information about that somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751352/5583468) has some pretty good information about that.

`rel="profile"` was dropped in HTML5, it may not be of a whole lot of use anymore. While it may be more useful to some of your users with older browsers, most search engines are probably disinterested with it now.

Comment: They say that the `profile="..."` attribute was dropped, but not the `rel="profile"`.

Comment: However, this links actually shows that you can have multiple links as I showed in my question (from the answer you pointed out!) http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-profile

Comment: profile has been dropped as an attribute value https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#linkTypes